# Spring Batch: FlatFileItemWriter to InputSteam/Byte array

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

So I've created a batch job which generates reports (csv files). I have been able to generate the the files seamlessly using FlatFileItemWriter but my end goal is to create an InputStream to call a rest service which will store the document or a byte array to store it in the database.

```
public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter<Report> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Report> reports) throws Exception {
        reports.forEach(this::writeDataToFile);
    }

    private void writeDataToFile(final Report data) throws Exception {
        FlatFileItemWriter writer = new FlatFileItemWriter();
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("C:/reports/test-report.csv"));
        writer.setLineAggregator(getLineAggregator();
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();
        writer.open(new ExecutionContext());
        writer.write(data);
        writer.close();
    }

    private DelimitedLineAggregator<Report> getLineAggregator(final Report report) {
        DelimitedLineAggregator<Report> delimitedLineAgg = new DelimitedLineAggregator<Report>();
        delimitedLineAgg.setDelimiter(",");
        delimitedLineAgg.setFieldExtractor(getFieldExtractor());
        return delimitedLineAgg;
    }

    private FieldExtractor<Report> getFieldExtractor() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Report> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Report>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(COLUMN_HEADERS.toArray(new String[0]));
        return fieldExtractor;
    }

}
```

One way I could do this is to store the file locally temporarily and create a new step to pick the generated files up and do the sending/storing but I would really like to skip this step and send/store it in the first step.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Why on earth this ugly contraption, which is also flawed and inefficient. How much data do you have, are you sure it will fit in memory. What about restartability etc.

Comment: The code I've described is a sample. The data is large yet to look at restartability. How else do I create a flat file?

Comment: You shouldn't wrap the writer just directly use the plain `FlatFileItemWriter` if you have a large amount of data you will run out of memory.

Comment: The reason I had to do that was each report type has sub reports. So I read the list of items for the metadata I receive in the report object I choose what to generate. I see what you're saying. I'll have to keep the FlatFileItemWriter generic and just let it do the job of writing it to flat file for the data given.

Comment: @M.Deinum - What if I have some metadata based on which the report has to be generated? Like the Columns the report has to have and the delimiter? The actual Report object has the metadata + actual List.

Comment: My original question still stays - Is there a possibility of creating an InputStream out of the file generated without having to store it locally?

Comment: Just use a different resource however as stated if you have quite some data you will run into memory issues. So I highly doubt that you really want that.